# How to map a XML ignoring namespace using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

I'm receiving a XML from a web service with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<string xmlns="http://someurl.com">somethingheresomethinghere</string>
```

And I'm trying to unmarshall this to a POJO that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="string")
public class StringValue {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    public StringValue () {
    }
}
```

And my unmarshalling code is this:

```
public T xmlToObject(Class<T> contextPath, Reader reader) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new XMLValidationEventHandler());
    T objectToConvert = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    return objectToConvert;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> unexpected element (uri:"http://someurl.com", local:"string"). Expected
>   elements are <{}string>

If the namespace in the XML were to be omitted from it, then it will work, but instead of altering the XML I want to know how can I make it so the namespace part doesn't cause me any trouble when marshalling or unmarshalling with JAXB.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the namespace using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://someurl.com", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB and namespace qualification on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: I think they mean they want to ignore the namespace entirely.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - That's what they said, I don't believe that's what they really want.

Comment: I'm going off of _If the namespace in the XML were to be omitted from it_. Could you configure JAXB to ignore the namespace?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I read that too.  They may not know it's possible to map the namespace so they are trying to ignore it.  If they really want to remove it here is an approach they can use:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html

Comment: I'm trying to use the `XmlSchema` annotation, but I get the error `Package annotations must be in file package-info.java`, should I place the annotation in said file?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - Yes it should go in a source file called `package-info.java` with just the contents from my answer with the package changed to match your model.  You can find an example here:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819

Comment: it worked, just to be safe, I have to add every namespace that may appear in the xmls I get from the web service?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - For a web service you only need to map the namespaces that correspond to the body of the message.  You wouldn't map the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace for example.

Comment: but for these situations where I get namespaces that have no relationship to our messages, how can I skip or ignore those namespaces in the XML?